# How to share the state from vuex store to all child components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am creating a custom form component with list of child components.
So in my parent component I have added vuex store that holds the state (data) that I want to share between my child component. All my components are single page components.

```
// CustomFormComponent.vue (parent component)
<template>
  <div>
   <form @submit='checkStateOfChildren()' >
     // Do a for loop on mySchema in store and dynamically detect the 
     // custom component based on individual node item in mySchema[]

     forEach Node in $store.mySchema[]
       render a custom component 
         // E.g <custom_text> or <custom_radio> ....
     ...
     <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
   </form>
  </div>
<template>

import store from '../store'; // Vuex Store
export default {
 store,

   created() {
   // ... populate store schema and model object to render the form elements

  },

  methods: {
     // Do the validation on the store.state.myModel and if everything is OK ... 
    // then do a post to backend
     checkStateOfChildren() {}
  }
}
```

And my store is like below

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
     state: {
        mySchema: {[ {custom_text_area schema}, {some component schema ...}, ...]}, 
        myModel: { custom_text_area_model, ...}
    },

    ... actions, mutations etc 
}
```

So how does each children can access the mySchema and myModel from VueEx store ?

**How do I implement a two-way state binding in the children custom components?**

Comment: It appears that I may have found the solution. All I have to do is include the store in my parent component and it will be automatically injected in to all child components and you can reference it (use it) by something like  this.$store. How elegant is that. And for more better state management I think I can import the    mapState, mapGetters, mapActions 
in every child component.

Answer (score 0):

I've generally used [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) for this.

I set it up so that computed property will read from Vuex in the `get()` function and then you can use the `set()` to commit it back to Vuex.